# How do I stop text from cutting off in the tkinter text widget in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

The text box is working, I can type in it, move it around and stuff but when my sentence reaches the end of the text widget, the last word just gets cut in half and moves the second half of the word to the next line. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: Did you try using the `wrap` option?

Comment: @acw1668 I've never heard of it, what does it do and how do I use it? Thanks!

Comment: See the [document](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.config-method).

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you! I fixed my problem by setting the wrap parameter to tkinter.WORD.

Answer (score 1):

This worked great for me.

If you add wrap=WORD to the parameters (or tk.WORD depending on how you imported tkinter) it won't cut your word in half if it reaches the end of a line, instead it will automatically make a new line if the word is too long

```
Text = tk.Text(root, height=13, width=20, wrap=WORD)
```

Comment: You can add more details on how it worked and why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Username acw1668 shared the [document](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.config-method) on the text widget and told me to look for the wrap parameter. I found that if you set the wrap parameter to tkinter.WORD, then the problem would be fixed.